# Sentence structure

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

> The game of chess is an example of a ________ information system: the pieces sit inertly on the board until the players move them according to known rules.
>
> 1. interactive
> 2. passive
> 3. cybernetic
> 4. disruptive
> 5. logistic

The given answer is *passive*. what is the problem if I choose *logistic*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the sentence following the colon speaks of pieces sitting inertly on the board, the more appropriate word is *passive*. What follows the colon explains why the game of chess is an example of passive information system, not a logistic information system.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic doesn't fit the sentence. "[T]he pieces sit inertly on the board until the players move them according to known rules" means passive.